# System.TypeLoadException when using System.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using a Core project to provide all datas to my Android project and my IOS project.

So in the Core Project I'm using a `WSHttpBinding` binding. It request the using of "`System.ServiceModel`".

The line "`using System.ServiceModel`" give me the "`System.TypeLoadException`" when the app is executing the "`using System.ServiceModel`".

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think Mono for Android supports `WSHttpBinding`, could be wrong though (don't have the time to look it up right now)

Answer (score 1):

It's not fully implemented yet. You can check [`Mono System.ServiceModel` class status here](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.ServiceModel) which is the difference between Mono and .Net.There are some `WSHttpBinding` hackings on [Mono's page](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_WSHttpBindingHacking) though.

Also, there is a similar question to this, and the accepted answer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687394/620138):

> Mono does not currently support WSHttpBinding, it is a work in progress, and the support is very spotty.