# Xamarin.iOS with SOAP 1.2

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to use a `SOAP 1.2` web service in `Xamarin.iOS` but I can't seem to find a way how to make it work. I added a ServiceRefence to my project, I can even send messages, but every time I send a message I get the following exception:

`System.Net.WebException: There was an error processing web request: Status code 415(UnsupportedMediaType): Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.`

I read that this message indicates, that I'm using a wrong binding. I should use `WsHttpBinding` instead of `BasicHttpBinding`, but I can't find `WsHttpBinding` in Mono.

Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449504/monotouch-wcf-wshttpbinding). I think `wsHttBinding` isn't supported still :(

Comment: Thanks @GSerjo I tried BahaiResearch.com's solutions, but still getting this error.

Comment: Do you really need ws* behavior? Try to use `customBinding`, you can set `SOAP1.2` with `basicHttBinding` this should work with monotouch. And of course you can add ssl for security sake

Comment: @GSerjo Something like this: http://www.pvle.be/2008/10/soap-12-message-format-with-basichttpbinding/ ?

Comment: Exactly, this should work perfactly